# Why does this weird purple tint appear over my prop icon when trying to spawn it in GMOD?

Tags: garrys-mod

Whenver I try to spawn a ragdoll or prop in Garry's Mod, this weird tint appears over it. I am given the option to delete, spawn it with a toolgun, etc. But I don't want to spawn it with a toolgun, I just want to click the icon and have the ragdoll/prop spawn. Why is this happening? And how can I fix it so I can just click the ragdoll/prop icon and have it spawn like it used to?

Comment: Is it purple and black? (If yes, you may want to remount or verify your content)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to sprint (or just plain holding shift) while trying to spawn the prop.
Simply release shift and click again to spawn the prop - if it persists, press shift a few times in and out of the Q menu - the game might think you're still holding it down.

Answer (score 0):

Holding "Shift" in the spawn menu selects entities; don't run and try to spawn stuff.  If it's purple and you want to un-purple it, just hold "Shift" and click it one more time.

It appears to me that the main purpose of this is so that you can edit the spawn menu's contents on the fly as if you're editing files in a system (which you are).  I don't see any practical way to use this though, as so far I only get the option to delete the model(s) when right-clicking them.

I found this out the hard way :)